Android bundle build failing while using new architecture with React Native 0.76.2
Created a new project and installed Bugsnag as only project dependency following the manual setup guide. App works fine on emulator/physical device, but when I try to build it, it throws the following error:

Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.

Upon further inspection, as the logs attached below states, no /Users/isaacmaldonado/Documents/Projects/Template/node_modules/@bugsnag/react-native/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/ were generated.
Steps to reproduce

Create new react native project with npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init <APP_NAME> --version 0.76.2
Follow react native manual setup guide
cd android folder and run ./gradlew bundleRelease
See error

Error messages:
> Task :app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: CMake Error at /Users/isaacmaldonado/Documents/Projects/Template/android/app/build/generated/autolinking/src/main/jni/Android-autolinking.cmake:9 (add_subdirectory):
C/C++:   add_subdirectory given source
C/C++:   "/Users/isaacmaldonado/Documents/Projects/Template/node_modules/@bugsnag/react-native/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/"
C/C++:   which is not an existing directory.
C/C++: Call Stack (most recent call first):
C/C++:   /Users/isaacmaldonado/Documents/Projects/Template/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:86 (include)
C/C++:   CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)
C/C++: CMake Error at /Users/isaacmaldonado/Documents/Projects/Template/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:89 (target_link_libraries):
C/C++:   Cannot specify link libraries for target
C/C++:   "react_codegen_BugsnagReactNativeSpec" which is not built by this project.
C/C++: Call Stack (most recent call first):
C/C++:   CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)

I created a minimal repository where issue can be reproduced: https://github.com/einjunge99/template (Remember to replace YOUR_BUGSNAG_API_KEY with your own Bugsnag API key on android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

If you don't add bugsnag to your application, does it build and run fine? Which version of bugsnag are you using?

Indeed, if I don't add Bugsnag the build is successful. I'm using @bugsnag/react-native 8.1.3.

Have you tried using a previous version of bugsnag? Might be an issue with their latest version.

Yes, I have not iterated through them all, but my main project, were this problem originally showed up, uses version 7.25.0. Went using the latest available on the reproducer but, as you can see, It had no effect.
